# determining the number of equable hyperrectangles with positive integer lengths and a given number of dimensions

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, fractions, rectangles

Two dimensional equable shapes are those shapes whose area and perimeter are numerically equal. There are only two rectangles that have the numerical equivalent of area and perimeter with positive integer lengths, the $3\times 6$ rectangle and the $4\times 4$ rectangle.

Proof: Let $d_1$ be the length of a rectangle on one dimension, $d_2$ be the length of a rectangle across the second dimension. WLOG let $d_1\ge d_2$. Then $2d_1+2d_2=d_1d_2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}=\frac{1}{2}$, $\quad\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{d_2}\ge\frac{1}{4}\Rightarrow 2<d_2\le 4\Rightarrow d_2=3$ or $d_2=4$. Pluging these into the equation the original $3\times 6$ and $4\times 4$ rectangles are obtained.

For the three dimensional case there are ten cuboids whose surface area and volume are numerically equal.

Proof: Let $d_1$ be the length of a cubiod on one dimension, $d_2$ be the length of a cubiod across the second dimension, and $d_3$ be the length of a cubiod across the third dimension. WLOG let $d_1\ge d_2\ge d_3$.  Then $2d_1d_2+2d_2d_3+2d_1d_3=d_1d_2d_3 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}=\frac{1}{2}$, $\quad\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{d_3}\ge\frac{1}{6}\Rightarrow 2<d_2\le 6\Rightarrow d_3=3$ or $d_3=4$ or $d_3=5$ or $d_3=6$.

Case 1: ($d_3=3$)
Replacing $d_3$ in the equation $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}=\frac{1}{2}$ gives the result $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}=\frac{1}{6}$, $\quad\frac{1}{6}>\frac{1}{d_2}\ge\frac{1}{12}\Rightarrow 6<d_2\le 12\Rightarrow d_2=7$ or $d_2=8$ or $d_2=9$ or $d_2=10$ or $d_2=11$ or $d_2=12$. $\quad \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{d_2}$ produces a unit fraction in all cases with the exception of $d_2=11$ which produces $\frac{5}{66}$. This results in five solutions (3,7,42),(3,8,24),(3,9,18),(3,10,15),(3,12,12)

Case 2: ($d_3=4$)
Replacing $d_3$ in the equation $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}=\frac{1}{2}$ gives the result $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}=\frac{1}{4}$, $\quad\frac{1}{4}>\frac{1}{d_2}\ge\frac{1}{8}\Rightarrow 4<d_2\le 8\Rightarrow d_2=5$ or $d_2=6$ or $d_2=7$ or $d_2=8$. $\quad \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{d_2}$ produces a unit fraction in all cases with the exception of $d_2=7$ which produces $\frac{3}{28}$. This results in three solutions (4,5,20),(4,6,12),(4,8,8)

Case 3: ($d_3=5$)
Replacing $d_3$ in the equation $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}=\frac{1}{2}$ gives the result $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}=\frac{3}{10}$, $\quad\frac{1}{5}\ge\frac{1}{d_2}>\frac{3}{20}\Rightarrow 5\ge d_2> \frac{20}{3}\Rightarrow d_2=5$ or $d_2=6$. $\quad \frac{3}{10}-\frac{1}{d_2}$ produces a unit fraction in all cases with the exception of $d_2=6$ which produces $\frac{2}{15}$. This results in one solution (5,5,10)

Case 4:($d_3=6$)
Replacing $d_3$ in the equation $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{d_3}=\frac{1}{2}$ gives the result $\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}=\frac{1}{3}$, $\quad\frac{1}{6}\ge\frac{1}{d_2}\ge\frac{1}{6}\Rightarrow 6\ge d_2\ge 6\Rightarrow d_2=6$. This results in one solution (6,6,6)

I can continue this process to find the number of solutions for higher dimensions, however it gets very tedious. I found a lower bound for the number of n-dimensional hyper-rectangles with positive integer lengths, whose (n-1) dimensional surface area and n-dimensional volume is numerically equivalent, based off of the solutions of the previous dimension.

The smallest fraction in the solution of the previous dimension can be broken into two parts in several ways to produce new solutions in the next dimension. Let $L_k$ be the largest number in the $k^{th}$ solution of (n-1) dimensions.  Let $f\in\Bbb{N}|\quad f|L_k$. We have $\frac{1}{L_k}=\frac{1}{L_k+f}+\frac{f}{(L_k+f)L_k}$. (Since $f|L_k$ the last fraction in the equation is a unreduced unit fraction) There are two more solutions in N dimensions which are (2N,2N,2N,…,2N[N times])  and (2N-1,2N-1,2N-1,…,2N-1[N-1 times],4N-2). We have the following lower bound formula:

$$S_N\ge 2+\sum_{k=1}^{S_{N-1}}d(L_k)$$

where $d(x)$ is the number of factors of $x$ and $S_N$ is the number of hyper-rectangles in n dimensions.

For example $S_3\ge 2+d(6)+d(4)=2+4+3=9$ ((3,10,15) isn’t counted)

Second example $S_4\ge 2+d(42)+d(24)+d(18)+d(15)+d(12)+d(20)+d(12)+d(8)+d(10)+d(6)=2+8+8+6+4+6+6+6+4+4+4=58$

question: can we find a formula for the number n-dimensional hyper-rectangles with positive integer lengths, whose (n-1) dimensional surface area and n-dimensional volume is numerically equivalent?

This is an equivalent question: can we find a formula for the number of ways $\frac{1}{2}$ can be written as the sum of n unit fractions?

Comment: I believe you made a typo at the beginning. It should be $2d_1d_2 + 2d_1d_3 + 2d_2d_3 = d_1d_2d_3 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2} + \frac{1}{d_3}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @VVejalla Fixed thanks for pointing it out. When I was typing this comment, I pressed @V and a small pop-up came up with your username on the top left of the comment box. I tried pressing it on my touch screen and I accedentally hit the flag on your comment. So I may have accententally flagged your comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's OK. I don't think flags have any effect unless they are deemed by the moderators to be on a bad comment.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted, quantus?

Comment: Are you still here, quantus?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: nobody knows.

In somewhat greater detail, the results for $2\le n\le6$ are tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A003167). The numbers are $2, 10, 108, 2892, 270332$. That's all anyone has been able to calculate. A reference is given to Gerald E. Gannon, Martin V. Bonsangue and Terrence J. Redfern, [One Good Problem Leads to Another and Another and...](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27970109?seq=1), Math. Teacher, 90 (#3, 1997), pp. 188-191. The 108 solutions for $n=4$ are listed [here](http://oeis.org/A003167/a003167.txt).

Comment: I looked through the links of your post and I like that you made an attempt to add information about the problem which is more than almost everyone else who looked at this problem. I also like that I now know about the solutions in higher dimensions without having to write a computer program for it. I also like that you put all of the important information from the oeis website in one convenient paragraph. In hindsight I should looked at oeis when I was creating my post. Oeis is a website I am familiar with and it is useful for discrete integer problems that involve a...

Comment: ...function or pattern, and in a few cases it is extremely useful because it sometimes contains information that is difficult to obtain otherwise. Even with all of that being said none of the links get me significantly closer to answering the question I asked. I looked at the prime factorization of the five numbers found and besides the learning that the sequence is super exponential I didn’t learn much about how to find the next one. I looked at the one good problem leads to another article (which I may have looked through it too quickly but,) from what I could gather it presents the...

Comment: ...process of how to get solutions in different dimensions, similarly to what I did in my original post for two and three dimensions but it does so by algebraically manipulating the equations in a different way. I am surprised by the fact that my lower bound formula is actually might novel information to the overall knowledge on problem. I am also surprised that only five of the numbers have been calculated. Even with it’s super exponential nature I quite sure that I could find the number for seven dimensions. Those are my thoughts on your post.

Comment: "none of the links get me significantly closer to answering the question I asked." It may just be that the question you asked is very hard. "I quite sure that I could find the number for seven dimensions." I hope you do, and that you'll then edit the new information into the OEIS, as well as posting it here.

Comment: I also note that you have the option of upvoting my answer by clicking the uparrow next to it, and/or "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Getting anywhere with $n=7$, quantus?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.